# Why does Erlang generate the same sequence of random number if applying the same seed?

Tags: erlang

I'm applying the following command to two erlang prompts, they all generate the same sequence of random number, so does it mean it is pseudo random in Erlang language? I'm curious about the rationale, since in Java, the sequence will not be the same even if I provide it with the same seed for two times. Many thanks!

```
random:seed(6, 6, 6).
random:uniform(100).
random:uniform(100).
...

the generated sequence: 12, 27, 79, 58, 90, 25, ...
```

Comment: all good, so work algorithm generating a pseudo-random number. If the on same seed is obtained different results - it means, the algorithm implemented is not correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is generally how traditional pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) have always worked, including Erlang's `random` module, which I think implements [Wichman-Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wichmann-Hill), but today's PRNGs are necessarily more sophisticated. In Erlang 18 you'll find a new [`rand` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html) that does not suffer the problem you're describing.

As you can see from the shell session copied below, you can just call the [`rand:uniform/0,1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html#uniform-0) functions from different processes without seeding, and the initial numbers in the various processes will be different:

```
1> rand:uniform().
0.10584199892675317
2> Self = self().
<0.1573.0>
3> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform() end), receive R -> R end.
0.9124422823012622
4> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform() end), receive R -> R end.
0.9476479571869831
5> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform() end), receive R -> R end.
0.037189460750910064
6> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform() end), receive R -> R end.
0.17698653918897836
```

The first call runs directly in the shell process. We then get the shell's pid, store it into `Self`, and spawn four processes in succession that each send the results of `rand:uniform/0` back to the shell, which receives it into `R`. As you can see, the four spawned processes each return different values, all of which differ from the value the shell got when it first ran `rand:uniform/0`.

If you want a number in a range other than 0-1, pass an integer `N` to [`rand:uniform/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html#uniform-1) and you'll get a value `V` in the range 1 <= `V` <= `N`:

```
7> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform(1234567) end), receive R -> R end.
510226
8> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform(1234567) end), receive R -> R end.
562646
9> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform(1234567) end), receive R -> R end.
250637
10> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform(1234567) end), receive R -> R end.
820871
11> f(R), spawn(fun() -> Self ! rand:uniform(1234567) end), receive R -> R end.
121252
```